# Replace comma with a line break in a pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, string, replace

Example of dataframe (called df_summary)below. In the 'Variant' column I am trying to replace any "," with a line break (I don't want a new table row, just a new line containing the value following the comma). Is there any way to do this? I tried:

```
df_summary['Variant'] = df_summary['Variant'].str.replace(',', '\n')
```

But it actually printed the character '\n' instead of adding a line break. Is what I am trying to code possible? I also considered using `str.split(','` and then couldn't find a way from there.

| Sample ID | Drug | Variant | Interpretation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 18RF0375-MI-TBWGS-NextSeq-2019-63_S54 | INH | fabG1 upstream_c.-15C>T,katG_p.Arg463Leu | INH-R |
| 18RF0375-MI-TBWGS-NextSeq-2019-63_S54 | RIF | No reportable variant detected | RIF-S |
| 18RF0375-MI-TBWGS-NextSeq-2019-63_S54 | PZA | No reportable variant detected | PZA-S |
| 18RF0375-MI-TBWGS-NextSeq-2019-63_S54 | FQ | No reportable variant detected | FQ-S |
| 18RF0375-MI-TBWGS-NextSeq-2019-63_S54 | EMB | embB_p.Glu378Ala | EMB-S |

Comment: [`df_summary.assign(Variant=df_summary['Variant'].str.replace(',', '<br>')).style`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Idcke.png) ?

Comment: @Timeless that line of code isn't working for me, but yes that is the result I am trying to get!